# Macro does not update selected row/column

Tags: vba, excel

Hope someone can help me as I am new on macros.

I have an issue when macros run in excel, the results should update the worksheet starting on 'F4' ( Range("F4").Select) however for some reason every time the macro run the results are updated/added in the first column (A4) even when the selection row and column is different

I reckon is a setup on excel as this was working correctly but I do not how/what was changed, this has a knock on effect on all my macros workbooks, help please!!!

```
Sheets("Month").Select
    Range("F4").Select
    con.Open "Database"
    sql = Sheets("SQL").Range("A1").Value
    con.CommandTimeout = 600
    rs.Open sql, con
    row = 3
    Do Until rs.EOF
        row = row + 1
        For col = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            Cells(row, col + 1) = rs.Fields(col)
        Next
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close
    con.Close
```

Comment: You should change that one part that points to the red thing. Honestly, though, how can we help you when you post no code, or even a blurry screengrab? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the macro is dropping in results starting in A4 has nothing to do with the cell that is selected before running the macro. This bit here determines where in the sheet that the data will be dropped:

```
row = 3
Do Until rs.EOF
    row = row + 1
    For col = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Cells(row, col + 1) = rs.Fields(col)
    Next
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

It says "Set variable `row` to `3`. Now loop through the recordset. Add `1` to `row` and loop through the fields in the recordset. Now paste the data for each field, starting in column `0+1` (or 1), in the row (which is now set to 4)." As this iterates through the fields it writes the data out, then moves to the next row.

To start writing the data in `F4` you can change that bit that actually writes the data out inside that loop:

```
row = 3
Do Until rs.EOF
    row = row + 1
    For col = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Cells(row, col + 6) = rs.Fields(col)
    Next
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Now the first cell written to will be the 4th row and 6th column (Cell F4).

All in all, this is a pretty slow way to grab the results from a recordset. You could probably change this whole module over to:

```
Sheets("Month").Select
Range("F4").Select
con.Open "Database"
sql = Sheets("SQL").Range("A1").Value
con.CommandTimeout = 600
rs.Open sql, con
Sheets("Month").Range("F4").CopyFromRecordset rs    
rs.Close
con.Close
```

And this would do the same thing without the messy iteration and confusing row/column math. It will also be much quicker if the recordset is large.

Comment: Fantastic!!! I have modified the query and it work brilliantly! and the time execution improve a lot. Thank you so much!!